# In my list I want to detect when it's -1 or 0 in length, otherwise I want it to return the second [1] index

Tags: python

[code challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kxWw.png)

The function second_item below returns the second item in the list l.

However, what if l has length 0 or 1? Then taking the second item makes no sense and will result in an error.

Change the code so that it detects these cases and returns -1 for lists of length 0 or 1, rather than causing an error.

For any other list, the function should still return the second item.

```
def second_item(l):
  if len(l) <= 1:
      return l
  else:
      return l[1]
```

The problem: the call `second_item([])` should return '-1', but it returned '[]'

Comment: Are you just looking to change `return l` to `return -1`? I'm not finding what you're asking very clear. It seems the code you have is already basically what you're after.

Comment: when i run it I get this "The call second_item([]) should return '-1', but it returned '[]'"

Comment: @Dfoxy, then `return -1` if the `if` is satisfied. Where in the code did you return `-1` ?

Comment: @Dfoxy Yes, read my comment again. Why are you returning `l`?

Comment: I'm after returning the second indexed value all the time except when my list length is smaller than -1 or is 0

Comment: @Dfoxy, we clearly understand what you need. Replace your `return`.

Comment: @Austin  Thank you so much i was stuck on it for hours :D

Answer (score 0):

Use an exception

```
try:
    return my_list[1]
except IndexError:
    return -1
```

The way it is now, `return l` returns a list, not a value

Comment: Solved - But thank you so much for your time was stuck on this problem for hours , i'm still new to programming :)